# Implementing revmap function with pattern matching or function composition

Tags: haskell, dictionary, pattern-matching, reverse, function-composition

Higher order function map Definition:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x:map f xs
```

Then how to write a revmap function with pattern matching/ using function composition?

Comment: You are doing pattern matching in the above example.

Comment: What do you mean by `revmap`?  Just `map` in the reverse order of the list?  If that is your intention, you could just do `map f . reverse`

Comment: OP, bheklilr gave you one answer - but you really have to tell us what `revmap` means. :-)

Comment: If you have performance concerns about `map f . reverse` needing to traverse the list twice – GHC is pretty good at optimising this kind of overhead away. If performance is really crucial, you shouldn't be using lists anyway but e.g. `Data.Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want something like OCaml's `rev_map` function:

```
revmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
revmap f xs = go xs []
  where
    go [] acc     = acc
    go (x:xs) acc = go xs (f x : acc)
```